# Google cloud platform after free trail

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I am using Only Maps service from google cloud platform, never used other services

Cloud platform : https://console.developers.google.com/

Firebase : https://console.firebase.google.com/

Firebase has some projects where i use FCM , After trail period do i have to upgrade .

Will it be suspended other wise , unable to find solution for particular query.

I am very much using only free services maps with in limits and FCM which is free service .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not Google's customers support.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically... use google search...

https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/

Comment: Billing if you don't upgrade

Having a billing account does not mean that your account is automatically upgraded to a paid account when the free trial ends. To protect your account from inadvertently accruing charges, when the free trial ends, your account is paused. The only way to upgrade and begin your paid account is to manually opt-in by opening the Google Cloud Platform Console and clicking the Upgrade button at the top.